# Can I render another controller's action from my current controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Might be a silly one but is it still possible to render an action from another controller in Rails 4?

Like this in UsersController:

```
def new
  @person = User.new        
  render 'schools/create_person'
end
```

For some reason it keeps rendering the new.html.erb instead of desired schools/create_person.html.erb

Comment: Or I should use something like this https://github.com/malev/render_component ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your routes and see if you have the method create_person in schools routes. If positive try [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to):

```
redirect new_school_person_path
```

with `new_school_person_path` as the route to that method.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I need to start another action not just render a view.

Answer (score 0):

It did not clear me what do you want

but I can suggest one way if you want to render the view

create a partial view (_create_person.html.erb) which are common for both `users` and `schools` and then

in `users` folder `new.html.erb`

`<%= render partial:  "schools/create_person" %>`

better you can make the partial view in shared folder in your views folder and render it

If you want to redirect

`redirect_to create_person_schools_url` #depends on your route define

Comment: Thanks. I don't want it to be partial since it works on it's own as an independent template.